# Composer dependency not met for large package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am needing to install a package into my Laravel project. I am using the latest version of Laravel (8), It comes preinstalled with;

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1"
```

When I go to install the new package, I get an error saying that it is not compatible with my project. When I check the composer.json file for the package, it give the following as a dependency;

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
```

I need this package to continue with my project. What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Please share more details. Either install Guzzle v6 **or** install Guzzle v7. There's no good way to install both

Comment: so basicly you need guzzle version 6 with Laravel 8 ?

Comment: The package is not maintained by me, but I have asked them to update ... But is it possible to include the package and then update the composer.json for the package? I dont want to downgrade my project

Comment: What package gives you this problem? You can check the available forks. Maybe someone has encountered this problem and already fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel v8 requires Guzzle v7. It is not compatible with Guzzle v6. If any package you want to use does not yet support Guzzle v7, you cannot use that package in your Laravel project - unless you downgrade Laravel to v7.

Updating the package from Guzzle v6 to v7 might not be that easy, as the [list of breaking changes](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) is not that short. But the maintainer of the package you want to use is surely pretty thankful if you provide a pull request to his repository

Comment: Sorry for the daft question, but if i created a pull request, would i need to change the `~6.0` to `~7.0.1`? ... Is that the corrrect syntax?

Comment: That depends on what you've changed. Keep in mind that changing the version number alone might not be enough (that's why I've mentioned the breaking changes)